# Stop the countdown after it reachs the exact date

Tags: javascript

I have a countdown until Christmas. But I am not able to make this countdown stops after it reaches the exact date.

```js
function countdown(){
 var now = new Date();
 var eventDate = new Date(2016, 11, 25);

 var currentTime = now.getTime();
 var eventTime = eventDate.getTime();

 // remaining time in miliseconds
 var remTime = eventTime - currentTime;

 // converting into seconds, minutes, hours, days
 var s = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
 var m = Math.floor(s / 60);
 var h = Math.floor(m / 60);
 var d = Math.floor(h / 24);


 // finding exact hours, minutes and seconds
 h %= 24;
 m %= 60;
 s %= 60;

 
 d = (d < 10) ? "0" + d : d;
 h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
 m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
 s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

 document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = d;
 document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = h;
 document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = m;
 document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = s;

 setInterval(countdown, 1000);
}



countdown();
```

```css
body {
 background: #1f262e;
}

.countdownContainer{
 position: absolute;;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform : translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 text-align: center;
 color: #eff0f2;
 padding: 10px;
}

.info {
 font-size: 80px;
}

#days, #hours, #minutes, #seconds {
 background: #0F1A20;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px 3px #1f262e;
 font-size: 120px;
 padding: 20px;
}

.title {
 font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table class="countdownContainer"  cellspacing="10">

 <tr class="title">
  <td style="padding-bottom: 20px">DAYS</td>
  <td style="padding-bottom: 20px">HOURS</td>
  <td style="padding-bottom: 20px">MINUTES</td>
  <td style="padding-bottom: 20px">SECONDS</td>
 </tr>

 <tr class="info" >
  <td id="days" border-spacing="10px"></td>
  <td id="hours"></td>
  <td id="minutes"></td>
  <td id="seconds"></td>
 </tr>
 
</table>
```

I looked at some examples and they are using `clearInterval`, but i am not sure how am i able to use it here.

Thanks

Comment: wait till Christmas .

Comment: `remTime = Math.max(remTime,0);`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol how do i use this?? can you please let me know

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol  man, your one line of code make me to try for some time and finally i made it work... Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple problem , here are some suggestions

1. Use `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()` because the former is a one-time event whereas the latter isn't so your set'ed intervals will keep on accumulating over and over , every second one additional is getting added untill browser gets overloaded or crash ? Well idk (browsers are pretty smart these days) but still clearing that enormous mess would require a huge army of `clearInterval()`s but did you note down the unique identifier for each `setInterval()` ? Oh no....
2. At each call `eventTime` and `currentTime` are being calculated (they are essentially unix timestamp in millisecs.) so even though former stays the same throughout the run , you would see the latter increase by 1000 upon each call , eventually a time comes when the latter equals/surpasses the former this is where you stop the process.

https://jsfiddle.net/oq2g7h0L/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clearInterval` like this

```
var myVar = setInterval(countdown, 1000);

function myStopFunction() {
  clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using clearTimeout.

```
var count;
function countdown() {
 count = setTimeout('decrement()', 1000);
}

clearTimeout(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't check if the dates are equal.

If today is the wanted date, then you should  stop the interval from running.

interval runs your function every milliseconds you give him as the second argument, so your function will run every second.

```
var myInterval = setInterval(countdown, 1000);

function countdown(){
    var now = new Date();
    var eventDate = new Date(2016, 11, 25);

    var currentTime = now.getTime();
    var eventTime = eventDate.getTime();

    // if today is equal Christmas date stop everything
    if (currentTime == eventTime) {
      return clearInterval(myInterval);
    }

    // remaining time in miliseconds
    var remTime = eventTime - currentTime;

    // converting into seconds, minutes, hours, days
    var s = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
    var m = Math.floor(s / 60);
    var h = Math.floor(m / 60);
    var d = Math.floor(h / 24);


    // finding exact hours, minutes and seconds
    h %= 24;
    m %= 60;
    s %= 60;


    d = (d < 10) ? "0" + d : d;
    h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
    m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
    s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

    document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = d;
    document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = h;
    document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = m;
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = s;

}
```

Comment: what excatly didn't work? its not Christmas yet so how do you know? :P

Comment: see a single line of code from `Niet the dark Absol` , this code makes my work complete... already a christmas party... haha

Comment: Sometimes just trying is all it takes :)

Comment: @surazzarus in your code, you never stop the intervals, and each time you run the function you set another interval, after 10 seconds you run the function 10 times in 1 second, add console.log to check it, make sure you will clear the interval before setting another one!

Comment: @YanMayatskiy yes you are right that i never stoped the interval in my code here.. i tried several ways on my own and couldn't make it work... and here i just put the setInterval without any stopping function so that i can find a right way